# How to support multiple Coordinate systems with ArcGIS Server 10.0 WMS?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, wms, coordinate-system, getcapabilities

I have a serve a number of wms Layers with ArcGIS Server (AGS) with the following coordinate system support - EPSG:25832, EPSG:31467, EPSG:4326 and CRS:84. As far as I can tell, AGS only supports 2 coordinate systems in the GetCapabilities document. Is this correct? Do I have another way to server wms layers in multiple Coordinate systems.

Comment: It's possible: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2007/09/26/adding-spatial-reference-systems-to-a-wms-services-capabilities-file/

Comment: Why is this task so extraordinarily long winded in AGS when it is a standard feature of geoserver and other FREE geoservers?

Comment: No idea, maybe there's a faster way to do it now? That was just the first reference I turned up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, only two coordinate systems are enabled. You'll need to log on to the server and edit a .cfg file to enable more coordinate systems. From the [ArcGIS Resource Center](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#//009300000057000000):

> Configuring the ListSupportedCRS parameter
>
> The ListSupportedCRS parameter can be used to add additional spatial
>   reference systems (such as EPSG:4267) to WMS services. By default, WMS
>   services only list two spatial reference systems; EPSG:4326 (or CSR:84
>   for WMS 1.3.0) and the spatial reference of the map service that WMS
>   is enabled on. By using the ListSupportedCRS parameter, you can
>   advertise more reprojection options to WMS clients by specifying
>   additional spatial references.
>
> The ListSupportedCRS parameter is not listed as a service property
>   when configuring WMS services in ArcCatalog or ArcGIS Server Manager.
>   To add the ListSupportedCRS parameter to a WMS service, you must edit
>   the service configuration file (.cfg) of the map service on which you
>   enabled WMS.